# Functioning code still gives 'cannot find module' warning and error

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am making a dropdown list that loads a simple `.svg` file to display next to a name. In the `img` tag the source is set to a function call that constructs the path. The path is correct and the picture is loaded correctly but warnings and errors are still thrown. Why?

This is for a Vue.js single page app, and I have tried checking the file path and removing some extraneous double qoutes but there is no effect. I am absolutely certain the source is in the `img` tag as identical code does not throw this warning/error combo and it is thrown once for each usage.

**Example**

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" v-if="showMenu">
    <li v-for="option in options" v-bind:key="option.id">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="updateOption(option)">
            <img :src=getImg(option.svgimg) alt="country flag" height="24" width="18" /> {{ option.name }}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**`getImg` Function**

```
getImg(picName) {
    return require("../image-assets/4x3/" + picName)
}
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsGYF.jpg)

I expect that it will render in the appropriate place, and it does but it also throws the following error for each `img` tag I use.

**Warning**

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error:
>   Cannot find module './function Image() { [native code] }'"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/components/Dropdown.vue
>           at src/components/EmergContactForm.vue
>             at src/views/EmergencyContactList.vue
>               at src/App.vue

**Error**

> Error: Cannot find module './function Image() { [native code] }'
>       at webpackContextResolve (eval at ./src/image-assets/4x3 sync recursive ^./.*$ (emergency-contacts.js:465), :269:11)
>       at webpackContext (eval at ./src/image-assets/4x3 sync recursive ^./.*$ (emergency-contacts.js:465), :263:11)
>       at VueComponent.getImg (Dropdown.vue?6c5b:65)
>       at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"08845f4c-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Dropdown.vue?vue&type=template&id=d436187e&
>   (emergency-contacts.js:71), :23:26)
>       at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3542)
>       at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
>       at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473)
>       at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462)
>       at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067)
>       at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409)

Comment: Do any of these help? https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/311#issuecomment-338474092